# Gnuplot: How to change line width of the points independently of the line width of the line?

Tags: gnuplot

When plotting with linespoints (`w lp`), I would like the width of the lines that draw the points to be 2, but the width of the plain line (i.e. what is seen when plotting `w l`) to be of width 1.

E.g. in the line

```
plot 'file.txt' u 1:2 w lp lw 2
```

can the argument `lw 2` be applied to the points only?

I do not want to change point size (e.g. via `ps 2`), because they will then be too large. I just want to increase the points' visibility by having them drawn with thicker lines.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood something in your question. If `ps 2` is too large, then set it smaller. `pointsize` also accepts floating foint numbers, e.g. `ps 1.25`.

**Code:**

```
### with linespoints: linewidth and pointsize
reset session
set key invert
set samples 3
set yrange[0:15]

plot \
    1.0 w lp pt 7 ti "lw, ps default", \
    2.0 w lp pt 7 lw 1 ps 1 ti "lw 1, ps 1", \
    3.0 w lp pt 7 lw 2 ti "lw 2, ps default", \
    4.0 w lp pt 7 lw 2 ps 2 ti "lw 2, ps 2", \
    5.0 w lp pt 7 lw 2 ps 1 ti "lw 2, ps 1", \
    6.0 w lp pt 7 lw 1 ps 2 ti "lw 1, ps 2", \
    7.0 w lp pt 7 lw 1 ps 1.25 ti "lw 1, ps 1.25"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I think the source of my confusion is the way in which lw and ps are coupled. Could you perhaps change the example to use any non-filled point type, e.g. `x`?

Comment: just exchange `pt 7` which is the circle to `pt 2` which is `x` or `pt 1` is `+`. With an interactive terminal simply type `test` and you will see the different patterns.